# why does the drive space used vary between two disk drives holding identical files

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, drive

I have two external NTFS USB drives with identical files but 5GB difference in used space. The drives are 500/1000 (465GB and 931GB) with 257GB and 252GB used. There is no fragmentation and no windows shadow storage on either.

I have run windows chkdsk and get very different results:

- file records processed 4832512 versus 119296
- large file records 11 versus 1
- reparse records 6272 versus 2
- security descriptor data files 10778 versus 10774
- files 108387 versus 108386

Should I be concerned at the 5GB leakage of space on the first/older drive or is this expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that can happen (among others) is that NTFS keeps a journal which records things that happen to files and folders, such as move, copy, update. This is kept in a large, fairly well hidden file. I doubt that it or it's content are reported through `chkdsk`. There are APIs to read from it...but the file itself is not generally accessible. If one volume was an active volume for some period of time, and the other is a backup, then this can account for a lot of hidden size difference.

Also, I noticed that the reparse points are somewhat numerous on one and almost non-existent on the other. A naïve backup can effectively destroy reparse points...and can undo hard links (pointers to files in various folders that are really not copies but links to the same file...kinda like shortcuts). For example, most of the files in c:\Windows\WinSXS are hard links to other files in other locations on the same volume. When copying files off, a program should be track and recover the structure of the reparse points and hard links. Depending on the utility used, these files can be accounted for differently.